# NextGen Gallery Breaks Other jQuery Plugins

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope, nextgen-gallery

I just installed [NextGen Gallery](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/) and NextGen Plus on my site, and it works as described on my galleries. However, it breaks the [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider I have on my homepage and the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) masonry arrangement I have on my blog page. I know NextGen is the issue because when I deactivate it, both the Slick slider and the Isotope blog page work perfectly. How do I determine what the problem is? Where do I look for the conflict?

**EDIT:** When NextGen is activated, looking at the console, I see this error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)". I click on the error and it refers me to the first line in my JS file `$(document).ready(function(){`. What's wrong with that line? I tried removing it, but then it throws other errors at me. I tried commenting out each function in my JS file, but the issue persisted no matter what. I've copied the entire contents of my JS file below, if that helps.

```
// Slick Carousel for Blog on Front Page
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.blog-post').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      touchMove: false,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      autoplay: false,
      dots: false,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1025,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 641,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false
          }
        }
      ]
    });
});

// Slick Post Slider
/*
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        dots: true,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: false
    });
});
*/

// Custom Services Dropdown
    function DropDown(el) {
        this.dd = el;
        this.initEvents();
    }
    DropDown.prototype = {
        initEvents : function() {
            var obj = this;

            obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
                event.stopPropagation();
            }); 
        }
    }

    $(function() {

        var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

        $(document).click(function() {
            // all dropdowns
            $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
        });

    });

// Isotope (Standard)
/*
    // initialize Isotope
    var container = $('.isotope-container');
    container.isotope({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });

    // filter items on button click
    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    });

    // layout Isotope again after all images have loaded
    container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      container.isotope('layout');
    });
*/

// Isotope (with Infinite Scroll)
  $(function(){

    var container = $('.isotope-container');

    container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
      });
    });

    // filter items on button click
    $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    });

    container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.pagination',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.next-post a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.isotope-item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          msgText: "loading new posts",
          img: 'http://uic.slamagency.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/uic-loading.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
```

Comment: Is it throwing a javascript (jQuery) or PHP (Wordpress) error? What errors messages is it displaying?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it isn't giving any error messages. The NextGen galleries work fine. It's just the other plugins that break...

Comment: did you check console ?

Comment: @pr1nc3 Looking at the console when NextGen is not activated, there are no errors. Looking at it when NextGen IS activated, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in my js file. But since it doesn't tell me what function has the error, how do I know what to fix?

Answer (score 2):

This is a jQuery conflict that happens all the time. To solve it, you simply assign the `$` symbol to `jQuery` as follows: 
`var $ = jQuery;` 
You should add it before this line: 
`$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Still works in 2020, with NextGen Gallery 3.3.6 and jQuery 3.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't solve this problem. You can find information on NextGEN gallery website that is possible to be in conflict with some other plugin and that can't be solved.

My suggestion is to look for some other gallery plugin.

Comment: I've tried looking on the NextGen site and Googling and asking for help on the Wordpress forums, but I haven't had any luck. Guess it's time to look for something else. :(

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same issue, here is the answer I found. I had to wrap all my custom JS in the following:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
   // Custom JS functions here.
});
```

Now all my JS works and NextGen works as well.